# Create Jenkins pipeline through CLI Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to create a pipeline through the command line, something like:

`jenkins-cli create pipeline --host <host_url> --jenkinsfile <jenkinfile>`

Or maybe a terraform plugin, or a python package.
It is doable with aws cloudformation and codepipeline, you just have to create a stack that creates a codepipeline project.

Comment: Do you mean a pipeline style job?

Comment: Yes, a pipeline style job.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that for people it would be a very important requirement to interact with Jenkins through a cli, rest api to be able to include it in scripts, #devops workflow, but it does not seem to be.

In this repo, there are some examples that answers my issue:

```
https://github.com/hoto/jenkinsfile-examples
```